# Installing Apache Solr 4.1 on windows 7

Tags: solr

How can i **install apache solr 4.1 search server** on **windows 7**
i went through out the net but i couldn't find any useful answer to my question

Comment: http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_0_0/tutorial.html OR http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrTomcat should get you started.

Comment: How to install Solr on Windows 8: http://www.lawruk.com/blog/55/how-to-install-solr-on-windows-8

Comment: You may like to try this articles: http://www.nopaccelerate.com/wiki/installing-apache-solr/ and http://www.nopaccelerate.com/wiki/configuring-apache-solr-to-use-with-nopaccelerate/ - it installs it on windows server 2008, but I have installed Solr on Win7 using same guide. Its the only detailed resource I'm able to find. Hope it helps you and others. thank you

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I can see that you're not familiar with Java Servlets and for such I would then recommend a nice Windows installer that not only Installs SolR, but also Apache.

http://bitnami.org/stack/solr

in a few clicks and no configuration changed, you will be up and running in a matter of minutes with a nice screen like:

[image]

By the way, Bitami not only provide you with a nice Windows Installer, but gives you as well a VM with Solr (so you can test it without screwing up your current system) plus a lot more methods to install and run SolR!

Answer (score 12):

Six easy steps to success...

1. Make sure Java is installed
2. Download Solr
3. Install and launch Solr (it comes with Jetty as the app server)

   1. This is a Java servlet, so don't expect an installer, just unzip the contents of the `.zip` file into a folder
4. Use examples and docs to learn Solr
5. Make your Solr install your own, using your own schema and documents
6. If on Windows 7 Server, set the Solr server jar to start automatically on start/reboot

Comment: Please could you give a detail description because i tried these steps and couldn't installed apache Solr because it is just zip file.

Comment: Mehdi, I really can't explain it any better. There are several sources out there, and of course the tutorial that comes in the Solr .zip. Look in the examples folder, and read the readme files for more links. Also, check this out: http://www.solrtutorial.com/solr-in-5-minutes.html

Comment: On step 3, open cmd, go to the subfolder "example" where you extracted the files and run "java -jar start.jar". That will start the servlet at http://localhost:8983. More instructions at http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_2_1/tutorial.html

Comment: Nice video o n installing Solr
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_3poE2yoao0